# Поиск опечатки при помощи регулярных выражений

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

В БД хранится n-е количество записей, содержащие, помимо прочего, ФИО клиентов - как одним полей, так и отдельные под каждую часть - фамилия, имя и отчество.
Задача найти клиенты-дубликаты, при этом возможны опечатки в 1-2 буквах ФИО, такие ситуации расценивать нужно как дубликаты. В структуре БД для поля с ФИО есть, само собой, unique key.

Я так понимаю, нужно брать первую запись, просматривать регулярным выражением записи со 2-й по n, затем 2-ю с 3-й по N и т.д.

Проблема в гипотетическом регулярном выражении. :) 
Гугление ничего не дало. Существуют ли готовые рецепты такого РВ?

Comment: Для начала нужно дать точное определение "опечатке" в вашем случае. Гугление, странно, что ничего не дало, есть алгоритмы поиска с заданной погрешностью, которые повсеместно используются в частности в поисковиках. Регуляркой это не решить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`regex` модуль](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) допускает приблизительное сравнение с тремя типами ошибок:

1) вставка;
 2) удаление;
 3) замена.

Например, чтобы определить, совпадает ли данное имя с точностью до двух ошибок с заданным списком:

```
>>> import regex
>>> match = regex.compile(r'(?e)\L<names>{e<=2}', names=['Иванов', 'Петров']).fullmatch
>>> match('Иванов')  # точное совпадение
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 6), match='Иванов'>
>>> match('Иванв')   # одно удаление
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 5), match='Иванв', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 1)>
>>> match('Ивав')    # два удаления                          
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 4), match='Ивав', fuzzy_counts=(0, 0, 2)>
>>> match('Ивв')     # нет совпадения (больше двух ошибок)
>>> match('Петрова') # одна вставка
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='Петрова', fuzzy_counts=(0, 1, 0)>
>>> match('Сидоров') # нет совпадения
```

Подобное использование регулярных выражений для *проверки правописания* не является эффективным (хотя если кол-во записей небольшое и проверку нужно провести только один раз, то можно и этот способ использовать).

Рекомендуемым чтением является статья Питера Норвига [How to Write a Spelling Corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) ([ссылка на русский перевод в конце статьи](http://gmdidro.googlepages.com/Ru_HowtoWriteaSpellingCorrector.html)), которая содержит реализацию простого алгоритма проверки правописания в 21 строк Питона и ссылки на статьи, описывающие более эффективные алгоритмы.

Чтобы найти клиенты-дубликаты можно поискать готовые Питон модули проверки правописания, если приведённые выше методы не являются достаточно эффективными.

Comment: @jfs,  большое спасибо за ссылку на  How to Write a Spelling Corrector. Прочел с удовольствием.

Answer (score 3):

Регулярки вряд ли такое могут сделать. Это не их работа.

Поэтому нужно будет писать цикл в цикле, который будет попарно сравнивать и оценивать "на опечатки". Для сравнения есть готовые методики, к примеру [Расстояние Левенштейна](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0).

Я так понимаю, что данное действие будет "одноразовым", поэтому выполнится оно за 10 минут или за час - не принципиально (то есть сильно оптимизировать не нужно). Но если размер базы достаточно большой, то тут нужно делать оптимизации. Первое, что я бы делал, это пробежался по именам. Их разновидности сильно ограничены и опечатки легко исправить. Точно также и с отчествами. А потом использовал имена как способ "сгруппировать" людей и просматривал каждую группу. Скорее всего, в каждой группе будет не очень много людей. (Доказательство - всего мужских и женских русских/украинских имен не так много, около 900 мужских и 1000 женских. Да, широко употребимых около 30-40. Поэтому, комбинация имя+отчество как минимум разделит на 1000 групп.)

Но тут не нужно забывать об одной заковырке. Не у всех имена написаны правильно. К примеру, я знаю девочку, чье имя пишется "Софья", но обычно употребляется форма "София". Или, к примеру, в Украине есть "Вячеслав" и "В’ячеслав" (разница в апострофе). Одному моему знакомому вот такая опечатка в отчестве стоила нескольких лет судебных разборок (его спутали с другим человеком, у которого такое же ФИО, только в отчестве не было апострофа).

Также нужно не забывать, что есть много людей с абсолютно одинаковыми ФИО. И это разные люди! Поэтому, думаю, правильно будет смотреть в дату рождения (если она есть). И если дата совпадает, тогда принимать решение о дубликате.